# Posting to google plus on user behalf python

Tags: python, google-api

Can we post on google plus on user behalf using an application? 
I am following this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

but it doesn't let me post but gives 403 forbidden error.

Any help?

Comment: Do you have an access token for the api?

Comment: Is the Google account a gmail.com user or a Google Apps for Work user? The Domains API you link to does not work for Gmail users.